# Combining 2 SUMS in MySQL and optimising query

Tags: mysql

I have the below code which works:

```
SELECT admin_teams.name,
SUM(temp_orders.amount_paid) as amount,
SUM(instalments.amount) as amount2
FROM temp_orders
LEFT JOIN admin_teams
ON admin_teams.id = temp_orders.team
LEFT JOIN instalments
ON instalments.order_id = temp_orders.order_id
WHERE 
(DATE(temp_orders.date_paid) = CURDATE()
OR DATE(instalments.date_paid) = CURDATE())
AND (temp_orders.pay_status = 4
OR instalments.pay_status = 4)
GROUP BY temp_orders.team
ORDER BY temp_orders.team ASC
LIMIT 5
```

It produces a table that looks like:

```
+-------------+--------+---------+
|    name     | amount | amount2 |
+-------------+--------+---------+
| team name 1 |    100 |     150 |
| team name 2 |    200 |     250 |
| team name 3 |   300  |     175 |
+-------------+--------+---------+
```

I have two issues;

1. I actually only want one column which is the sum of amount and amount2.
2. The query is VERY slow - this took 190 sec to run.

I did have it almost working with a Union which was almost instant - I couldn't however get it fully working because the number of columns in my first select statement will not match those in the second - the table 'instalments' does not have a team column but the table temp_orders does.

Can anyone help with either problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Put an `EXPLAIN` before your query and run it.Edit your question with the results

Comment: A friend suggested this but apparently the server is not set-up for EXPLAIN (I don't understand why, apparently something isn't installed or isn't updated) and I don't have access, or the knowledge to update it.

Comment: I never heard of such a thing,EXPLAIN comes with mysql,there`s no need to update anything

Comment: Alright edit your question Monday with some sample data,maybe a fiddle and leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT admin_teams.name,
(SUM(temp_orders.amount_paid) + SUM(instalments.amount))  as amount,
FROM temp_orders
LEFT JOIN admin_teams
ON admin_teams.id = temp_orders.team
LEFT JOIN instalments
ON instalments.order_id = temp_orders.order_id
WHERE 
temp_orders.date_paid >= CURDATE()
OR instalments.date_paid >= CURDATE())
AND (temp_orders.pay_status = 4
OR instalments.pay_status = 4)
GROUP BY temp_orders.team
ORDER BY temp_orders.team ASC
LIMIT 5
```

And add these indexes

```
ALTER TABLE temp_orders ADD KEY (date_paid ,pay_status,team);
ALTER TABLE instalments ADD KEY (date_paid ,pay_status);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I can't actually make alterations myself so testing that will have to wait until Monday. I've tried combining the columns as you've suggested which works in the sense that it returns a single column, it doesn't however give the correct values. I can't be much more helpful as I don't actually know how it's retrieved the values that it is showing.